# How to convert nvarchar m/d/yy to mm/dd/yyyy in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

Input is nvarchar that varies in format from `m/d/yy` to `mm/dd/yyyy`. How can this be converted to `mm/dd/yyyy` in SQL? So far the `CONVERT()` function works for the format `m/d/yyyy` but errors for `m/d/yy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast it as a date like so:

```
cast(@m + '/' + @d + '/' + @y as datetime)
```

or similarly

```
cast('m/d/yy' as datetime)

cast(Fieldnamehere as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

`update table_name set column_name = convert(varchar,cast(column_name as date),101)`  or if a select statment `select convert(varchar,cast(column_name as date),101)`

Answer (score 0):

There's usually some additional nuances in the data, but here's a starter template I've been able to come up with... Just replace the debug text with `convert(datetime2, [DateNVarChar], 101)`.

```
CASE 
    -- x/y/zzzz to xx/yy/zzzz
    WHEN SUBSTRING([DateNVarChar], 2, 1) = '/' AND SUBSTRING([DateNVarChar], 4, 1) = '/' THEN
        'x/y/zzzz: ' + '0' + SUBSTRING([DateNVarChar], 1, 2) + '0' + SUBSTRING([DateNVarChar], 3, 20)

    -- xx/y/zzzz to xx/yy/zzzz
    WHEN SUBSTRING([DateNVarChar], 3, 1) = '/' AND SUBSTRING([DateNVarChar], 5, 1) = '/' THEN
        'xx/y/zzzz: ' + SUBSTRING([DateNVarChar], 1, 3) + '0' + SUBSTRING([DateNVarChar], 4, 20)

    -- x/yy/zzzz to xx/yy/zzzz
    WHEN SUBSTRING([DateNVarChar], 2, 1) = '/' AND SUBSTRING([DateNVarChar], 5, 1) = '/' THEN
        'x/yy/zzzz: ' + '0' + [DateNVarChar]

    ELSE
        'Normal: ' + [DateNVarChar]
END as [FormattedDate]
```